# background-position bottom parseInt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, position

I have a script for animating a background-position while scrolling.

The background-position of the image: center bottom.

When scroll the script will start from the center top position.

Any idea how it will start with parseInt from the bottom background-position?
I have looked all over but cant find what to do.

```
<script> 
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    var x = $(window).scrollTop(); 
        $('.container_image).css('background-position', 'center ' + parseInt(-x / -3) + 'px');
 }); 
</script>

div .container_image{
background-image: url("../images/image.jpg");
background-position: 50% bottom;
background-color:#fff;
min-height:325px;
height:325px;
-moz-transition: height 0.3s ease 0s;}
```

Comment: Do you have to use parseInt()?

Comment: If I remove that part, the scrolldelay wont work...

Comment: and calculating the position beforehand doesn't work? i.e. var newPos = (-x/-3); $('.container_image).css('background-position', 'center ' + newPos + 'px');

Comment: Works beautifully! many thanks. It works, but has an extra bottom of 18px, so I'll have to figure out how to remove that padding.

Comment: Putting it in brackets would also have worked (so just removing `parseInt`)

Comment: It would have but I thought for demonstration purposes be very clear about it.

Comment: Did no-one notice the missing `'` after `.container_image`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the value beforehand would work to fix your problem.

```
var newPos = (-x/-3);
$('.container_image').css('background-position', 'center ' + newPos + 'px');
```

or as Thomas suggested

```
$('.container_image').css('background-position', 'center ' + (-x/-3) + 'px');
```

would also work.